# T-SQL Combine rows in continuation

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like the following.
What I want is the the rows in continuation of each other to be grouped together - for each "ID".
The column IsContinued marks if the next row should be combined with the current row

My data looks like this:

```
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| ID  | Period | IsContinued | StartDate | EndDate  |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 1      | 1           | 20180101  | 20180404 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 2      | 1           | 20180501  | 20180910 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 3      | 0           | 20181001  | 20181201 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 4      | 1           | 20190105  | 20190228 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 5      | 0           | 20190401  | 20190430 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 2      | 1           | 20180201  | 20180215 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 3      | 0           | 20180301  | 20180401 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 4      | 0           | 20180501  | 20180530 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 5      | 0           | 20180701  | 20180705 |
+-----+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

The end result I want is this:

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| ID  | PeriodStart | PeriodEnd | StartDate | EndDate  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 1           | 3         | 20180101  | 20181201 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 123 | 4           | 5         | 20190105  | 20190430 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 2           | 3         | 20180201  | 20180401 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 4           | 4         | 20180501  | 20180530 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 456 | 5           | 5         | 20180701  | 20180705 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

DDL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #Period (ID INT, PeriodNr INT, IsContinued INT, STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE)
INSERT INTO #Period VALUES (123,1,1,'20180101', '20180404'),
                      (123,2,1,'20180501', '20180910'),
                      (123,3,0,'20181001', '20181201'),
                      (123,4,1,'20190105', '20190228'),
                      (123,5,0,'20190401', '20190430'),
                      (456,2,1,'20180201', '20180215'),
                      (456,3,0,'20180301', '20180401'),
                      (456,4,0,'20180501', '20180530'),
                      (456,5,0,'20180701', '20180705')
```

The code should be run on SQL Server 2016

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the order of the rows is determined by the `Period` column? 
Also, sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Way to go on the sample data! Now all you need to [edit] into your question is your attempt to solve the problem yourself... For more information, read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
with removeFluff as
(
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT ID, PeriodNr, IsContinued, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, LAG(IsContinued,1,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PERIODNR) Lag
        FROM #Period
     ) A
WHERE (IsContinued <> Lag) OR (IsContinued + Lag = 0)
)    
,getValues as
(
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN LAG(IsContinued) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PeriodNr) = 1 THEN LAG(PeriodNr) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PeriodNr) ELSE PeriodNr END PeriodStart,
       PeriodNr PeriodEnd,
       CASE WHEN LAG(IsContinued) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PeriodNr) = 1 THEN LAG(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PeriodNr) ELSE STARTDATE END StartDate,
       EndDate,
       IsContinued
FROM removeFluff r
)

SELECT ID, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd, StartDate, EndDate
FROM getValues
WHERE IsContinued = 0
```

Output:

```
ID  PeriodStart PeriodEnd   StartDate   EndDate
123    1           3        2018-01-01  2018-12-01
123    4           5        2019-01-05  2019-04-30
456    2           3        2018-02-01  2018-04-01
456    4           4        2018-05-01  2018-05-30
456    5           5        2018-07-01  2018-07-05
```

Method:

- `removeFluff` cte removes lines that are unimportant.  Theses are the records that don't start or end a segment (line 2 in your sample data)
- Now that the fluff is removed, we know that either:
- A.) The line is complete on it's own (`LAG(IsContinued) ... = 0`), ie. previous line is complete
- B.) The line needs the "start" info from the previous line (`LAG(IsContinued) ... = 1`)
- We apply these two cases in the `CASE` expression of the `getValues` cte
- Last, the results are narrowed to only the important rows in the final select with `IsContinued = 0`.  This is because we have used `LAG` to get "start" data on the "end" data row, so we only want to select the end rows